# How to fix infinite Promise loop at end of client.release() in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, promise, node-postgres

Here is my code that I'm trying to implement using node-postgres:

```
    return pool.connect().then((client) => {
        //  if (err) {
        //      throw err;
        //  }
            let updateTable = [];

            console.log('ABOUT TO RUN QUERY');

            // updateTable.executeQuery()
            return client.query(sqlString, updateTable, (error, result) => {
                console.log('RUNNING QUERY');
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                }
                console.log('RUNNING QUERY2');
                // code
                console.log('RUNNING QUERY3');

                for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log('RUNNING QUERY4');
                    let row = result.rows[i];
                    // process data
                }
                console.log('RUNNING QUERY5');
                // write to file
                console.log('RUNNING QUERY6');

                return client.release();
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('CLIENT RELEASED');
                if (!fileOnly) {
                    if (optionNode != null) {

                            console.log('ABOUT TO RUN QUERY #2');

                            // statsTable.executeQuery()
                            let statResults = client.query(withStatsString, statsTable, (err, res) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    return err;
                                }

                                return client.release();
                            });
                        //}
                    }
                }
                return pool.end();
            })
            .then(() => {
                return reportObject;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                throw e;
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            return reportObject;
        });
```

When I run this code, I can see:

```
RUNNING QUERY
RUNNING QUERY2
RUNNING QUERY3
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY4
RUNNING QUERY5
RUNNING QUERY6
```

However, it **never** reaches the `then` where the client is released. I will print out literally right before ending the `Promise`, but will hang infinitely and never resolve. How do I fix my Promise chain?

EDIT: I was able to fix the `client.query`, but in the `index.js`, my program is hanging on completion. This is the code:

```
ReportUtil.sendInReport('Monthly_2017_01', JSON.parse(reportRequest), 100, null)
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.status);
    console.log(result.header);
    console.log(result.data);
    return Promise.resolve();
}).finally(() => {});
```

After this code, it just hangs and the program never ends. How do I escape this Promise chain?

Comment: Don't `return client.release();` try just: `client.release();`

Comment: What exactly is `client.query` that does both take a callback and return a promise? Looks sketchy.

Comment: `.catch(e => {
                throw e;
            });` is pointless, drop it.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah usually I wouldn't have that code in production, I was just fishing trying to figure out what was broken. It turns out that using the callback instead of the Promise seems to be why I couldn't return from it.

Comment: Yes, avoid callbacks when an API supports promises.

Comment: It doesn't help that I copied from their documentation where they use callbacks everywhere XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs on the [release callback](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#releasecallback):

> You must call the releaseCallback or client.release (which points to
>   the releaseCallback) when you are finished with a client. If you
>   forget to release the client then your application will quickly
>   exhaust available, idle clients in the pool and all further calls to
>   pool.connect will timeout with an error or hang indefinitely if you
>   have connectionTimeoutMills configured to 0.

Try not returning the `client.release` (like it is a promise - which it is not) but just calling it lower in the promise chain like this:

```
return pool.connect().then((client) => {
    let updateTable = [];

    console.log('ABOUT TO RUN QUERY');

    // updateTable.executeQuery()
    return client.query(sqlString, updateTable)
    .then(result => {
        console.log('RUNNING QUERY');
        console.log('RUNNING QUERY2');
        // code
        console.log('RUNNING QUERY3');

        for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
          console.log('RUNNING QUERY4');
          let row = result.rows[i];
          // process data
        }
        console.log('RUNNING QUERY5');
        // write to file
        console.log('RUNNING QUERY6');
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (!fileOnly) {
          if (optionNode != null) {

            console.log('ABOUT TO RUN QUERY #2');

            // statsTable.executeQuery()
            let statResults = client.query(withStatsString, statsTable)
            .then(res => {

            });
          }
        }
        client.release();
        console.log('CLIENT RELEASED');
        return pool.end();
      })
      .then(() => {
        return reportObject;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        client.release();
        throw e;
      });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    return reportObject;
  });
```

And for exiting your `index.js` using a Promise chain:

```
ReportUtil.sendInReport('Monthly_2017_01', JSON.parse(reportRequest), 100, null)
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.status);
    console.log(result.header);
    console.log(result.data);
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
})
.finally(() => {
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Wait, so `client.release()` doesn't double as a Promise but `pool.end()` does? Such a confusing library. Thanks for the answer, I'll see if I can get it working now.

Comment: I agree the documentation seems to be lacking considerably.

Comment: So it turns out that because I was using the `client.query` callback, it was not returning a `Promise` and was completely stalled in that function because of it. I edited your answer to reflect this. I now have it going to the very end of my program, but it is still hanging, even after completing all the work.

Comment: does it hang @ return pool.end();?

Comment: It's making its way all the way up the stack to my `index.js` where it prints the header and data that is generated by the report, and then just hangs. I edited my question to try showing what it's doing.

Comment: Alright, I don't know if this is the correct way to end a Node.js script, but I just added a `process.exit()` to the end of it and now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked out on the end. Just FYI about the process.exit as it is not recommended practice: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code